# How to use preg_match correctly inside an array index?

Tags: php, regex

code:

```
$array[ ( preg_match( '/pdf-\d/', $key ) ? true : false ) + '[' + ( preg_match( '/pdf-total-\d/', $key ) ? true : false ) + ']' ]
```

output should be:

```
$array['pdf-1[pdf-total-1]']
```

Comment: You haven't done yourself any favors cramming that all onto one line.

Comment: `preg_match( '/pdf-\d/', $key )` will return true or false, you dont need the `? true : false`, if you use `preg_match( '/pdf-(\d)/', $key )` this will return one array with the (\d) found

Comment: Thanks for reply guys, but I figured out it myself. I just appended a hidden input in my jquery with value and match it in my php. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @nicearma: oh! `preg_match` returns 0 when there is no match, 1 when a match is found, false when an error occurs.

Comment: @nicearma: even if you use a capture group `preg_match` will not return the matched content!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you are using ternary operator:

```
preg_match( '/pdf-\d/', $key ) ? true : false
```

This returns `true` or `false` but never `pdf-1` nor `[pdf-total-1]`

Maybe you want more something like this:

```
$array[ 
        ( preg_match( '/pdf-\d/', $key ) ? $key: false ) . 
        '[' . ( preg_match( '/pdf-total-\d/', $key ) ? $key: false ) . ']' 
      ]
```

But it doesn't have much sense in any case because `$key` matches the first pattern **or** it matches the second